# how to traverse through a datagrid and copy the rows to a other datagrid based on checkbox.checked in the code behind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datagrid, code-behind

Hi I have two datagrids as below
   with id="x"

```
                               <Columns>
                                   <asp:BoundColumn DataField="qid" HeaderText="ID" ReadOnly="True" 
                                       Visible="False"></asp:BoundColumn>
                               <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderStyle-Width="40px" HeaderText="Main Only"                                           ItemStyle-Width="40px">
                                       <ItemTemplate>
                                           <asp:CheckBox ID="chkmain" runat="server"
                                                         Checked=False /> 
                                       </ItemTemplate>
                                   </asp:TemplateColumn>

                               </Columns>

                           </asp:DataGrid>
```

and
id="y"

```
                               <Columns>
                                   <asp:BoundColumn DataField="qid" HeaderText="ID" ReadOnly="True" 
                                       Visible="False"></asp:BoundColumn>
                             <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderStyle-Width="40px" HeaderText="Main Only" 
                                       ItemStyle-Width="40px">
                                       <ItemTemplate>
                                           <asp:CheckBox ID="chkmain" runat="server"
                                                         Checked=False /> 
                                       </ItemTemplate>
                                   </asp:TemplateColumn>

                               </Columns>

                           </asp:DataGrid>
```

I am trying to copy the rows with the checkbox is selected is true on clicking a **add** button, could anyone help me with the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop on rows on first grid. Create new DataTable with same number of column you need in 2nd grid. Get checkbox object using FindControl("chkmain") in the loop. if checkbox if checked , create new row in new datatable and add required text in it. and at last bind new datatable to 2nd grid. 
I hope you will understand from the description.